# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ko' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to use **Knockoutjs** in a **ASP.NET MVC 5** Project, but the system is complaining about it...

Here is the error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 166, column 9 in
http://localhost:1525/Authors/Index

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ko' is undefined
```

Here is my script:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    function ViewModel(authors) {
        var self = this;
        self.authors = authors;
    };
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
}
```

I have no build errors; only when I run the App it return this error... I'm using the latest NuGet packages, including Knockoutjs 3.3.0.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ok basic question first, have you referenced KO JS file in your view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the scripts that nuget added into your project on your page:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type= 'text/javascript' src='/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js' ></script>
    <script>
        function ViewModel(authors) {
            var self = this;
            self.authors = authors;
        };
        var viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
}
```

Your filename may be different, look in your solution explorer.

Comment: hello @br4d, when I add the second line you show me, it works. But I had to add it to all my Views. Is this the best approach? Or is it possible to declare it only once - and reference it when needed? Cheers, Cesar.

Comment: Yes. Reference it in your Layout file before where you render the Scripts sections.

Comment: You may want to look into ASP.NET MVC bundling as well, to simplify this.